# Ruby LDAP: works outside of foreman + sinatra, but not inside

Tags: ruby, ldap

I've set up the `Adauth` gem so that it can connect to my ActiveDirectory, and successfully returns an object when I do (from a standalone script):

```
require 'adauth'

Adauth.configure do |c|
  c.server = "server"
  c.port = 389
  c.base = "DC=company,DC=org"
  c.domain = "company.org
end

Adauth.authenticate('username','password')
```

And also successfully returns `nil` if I put an incorrect password in for the user.

However as soon as I put this inside a sinatra app, the `authenticate()` call returns `nil` even if I hardcode correct credentials.

If I poke around with internals it looks as though the LDAP `.bind` call is returning `nil` when I'm inside sinatra, and `true` when I'm running standalone. Any ideas why this would be and how I could fix it?

Many thanks!